Invalid signature for file maven deployment
The post is to provide a solution that worked for me. Focus on the guide for the deployment process https://central.sonatype.org/publish/publish-portal-maven/ and the corresponding link in the note section for additional data -> https://central.sonatype.org/publish/publish-maven/

Don't forget to publish your GPG key in the keyserver.ubuntu.com refer to the manual -> https://central.sonatype.org/publish/requirements/gpg/#distributing-your-public-key
In your pom.xml add <phase>package<phase> to the maven-source-plugin and maven-javadoc-plugin, see below

<plugins>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.source.plugin}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            **<phase>package</phase>**
            <goals>
                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${maven.javadoc.plugin}</version>
<configuration>
    <doclint>none</doclint>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
        **<phase>package</phase>**
        <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
...
</plugins>


I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question
